# How to remove single row from xgb.DMatrix

Tags: r, matrix, xgboost

I have a xgb.DMatrix with 42 rows and 50 features. I would like to remove a single row (let say row 5) and create a new DMatrix in this way containing 41 rows. I can easily do this when working with a normal matrix using e.g.

```
myMatrix<— matrix(c(1:50),nrow=5)
subMatrix<—myMatrix[-5,]
```

However, when I convert myMatrix with xgb.DMatrix the above approach doesn’t work.

I have tried to use the "slice" command but am not sure how to remove only a single row which is not necessary the first or the last one.

Comment: Have you tried `myMatrix <- slice(myMatrix, c(1:4, 6:42)`?

Comment: I have just tried but gives error: Error in UseMethod("slice_") : 
  no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "xgb.DMatrix"

Comment: Are you using `dplyr` as well? You might have to specify you’re using `xgboost::slice`

Comment: That was it, it works now, thank you Sven!